# storing fpdf output in server and add filename in database

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am generating invoices using fpdf library which fetches data from database,now when the pdf is generated i want to save the file in a folder and add the file name with date in database so that i can fetch the all invoices generated previously in a table.Please help me out here.

Comment: Have you created the table and the folder? Did you manage to save the file? Not sure where to start helping without knowing your concrete problem

Comment: @Philipp  by far i'm able to genrate pdf but i want to save the generated pdf to some folder and add the file name in database,so that i can call the file name from database to get the pdf.

Something like image upload.We upload image in database move uploaded file to some folder and add blob data in database of the image.

Comment: It's the same as an image upload. So what's the problem?

Comment: i tried writing sql queries but it doesn't works

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require 'connection.php';

class SimpleTable extends FPDF
{
function generateTable($no)
{
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
$this->cell(20,10,$no,1,0,"C");
$this->cell(20,10," * ".$i,1,0,"C");
$this->cell(20,10," = ".$i*$no,1,1,"C");
}
}
}
$pdf=new SimpleTable();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->generateTable(5);
$content= $pdf ->Output();
$sql="INSERT into pdfs(file)VALUES ($content)";
if (mysqli_query($db,$sql)) {
 echo "<script>alert('done');</script>";}
else{ echo "no";}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be shure that you can write to the directory.

```
$filename="/Mydirectory/bill01.pdf";
```

Save the Pdf.

```
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

Update the Sql Tables

```
$query=" UPDATE `shopdb`.`bills` SET `bill_doc_crea` = '1', `bill_pdf_doc` = '".$filename."' WHERE `bills`.`ordernummer` ='".$orderId."' ;";
```

Comment: Thanks man, but using the F parameter will force download it to the specified location.Is there any way so that i can open the pdf file inline in browser and download it in the same while adding the file in database.

Answer (score 0):

Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])

Destination where to send the document. It can be one of the following:

```
I: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available.
D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
S: return the document as a string.
```

Normally the Parameter F should only save to disk.
It looks that fpdf are forcing download.
In this case use of tcpdf https://tcpdf.org/ should be useful.
I use it and it works fine. Save to disk and insert in DB

Comment: thanks a ton mate, i followed your suggestion with some mods and completed the task. See below once and do tell if it is ok.

$pdf=new SimpleTable();
  $a = md5(uniqid());
$b = substr($a, 5, -20);
$c="PO-16-17-".$b;
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->generateTable(5);
$path="pdfs/$c.pdf";
$filename="$c.pdf";
$content = $pdf ->Output($path,"F");
$sql="INSERT into pdfs(file) VALUES ('".$filename."')";
if (mysqli_query($db,$sql)) {
 # code...
 echo "<script>alert('done');</script>";
}
else{
 echo "no";
}